# GetCurrentPublishing page with SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there anyway to get current publishing page with SharePoint API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use code like the following to do this. Depending on the context of where you're calling it, you can be more or less defensive accordingly.

```
    var li = SPContext.Current.Item as SPListItem;
    if (li != null && PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(li))
    {
        var pp = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(li);
    }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot after some resultless searching, hence the bounty, thanks.